# Why does the fire look like it's made of squares?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, smoke-simulation, fire

Does any one have an idea why the fire looks like made of squares? I am rendering in high resolution and high  resulution devisions (100). Nothing I tried helped. Fire is in motion and there is wind around.

[image]

Comment: BY THE WAY I AM WORKING WITH CYCLES

Comment: I guess it's pretty normal because these are voxels, hum did you like zoom in really in? I am not very skilled but I guess that's normal because voxels are cube-like pixels and the fire is voxel's based. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Might be not-applied scale of emitter/domain objects, no cubic interpolation between voxels (linear interpolation), but probably just too low domain divisions. 100 is like nothing. Problem with Blender is when you increase the divisions, your simulation changes, so you can't test on low and render high. And high-res divisions only add noise on top and don't solve the underlying issue. You might want to try Houdini (free apprentice version) to do simulations.

Comment: THANKS FOR YOUR ANSWER